# Date list using javascript simple

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Hello guys could give me a little help ?

Code here https://jsfiddle.net/pedrowperez/hgb5ufqw/2/`

this is my work.

HTML

```
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>
<p id="demo5"></p>
<p id="demo6"></p>
<p id="demo7"></p>
```

Javascript

```
var someDate = new Date();
var Ano_Confirmado = someDate.getFullYear();
var Mes_Confirmado = someDate.getMonth();
var Dia_Confirmado = someDate.getDate();
var Week = 7;
var Day = 1;
var someDateD = new Date(Ano_Confirmado, Mes_Confirmado, (Dia_Confirmado) - Week);


document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = (someDateD);
someDateD.setDate(someDateD.getDate() + Day);
document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = (someDateD);
someDateD.setDate(someDateD.getDate() + Day);
document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = (someDateD);
someDateD.setDate(someDateD.getDate() + Day);
document.getElementById('demo4').innerHTML = (someDateD);
someDateD.setDate(someDateD.getDate() + Day);
document.getElementById('demo5').innerHTML = (someDateD);
someDateD.setDate(someDateD.getDate() + Day);
document.getElementById('demo6').innerHTML = (someDateD);
someDateD.setDate(someDateD.getDate() + Day);
document.getElementById('demo7').innerHTML = (someDateD);
```

Result

```
Tue Jan 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (E. South America Daylight Time)

Wed Jan 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (E. South America Daylight Time)

Thu Jan 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (E. South America Daylight Time)

Fri Jan 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (E. South America Daylight Time)

Sat Jan 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (E. South America Daylight Time)

Sun Jan 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (E. South America Daylight Time)

Mon Feb 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (E. South America Daylight Time)

Tue Feb 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (E. South America Daylight Time)

Wed Feb 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (E. South America Daylight Time)
```

I need to change the date format : Wed Mar 23 2016 15:19:36 GMT-0300 (E. South America Standard Time)
for this format: DD/MM

But I can not find anything Referring dates will list in javascript;

Comment: I think you might find this thread helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options that come to mind:

1. Use the `Date` methods, though this is relatively limiting
2. Use a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

**Using `Date` methods**

```
 someDate.getDay() + '/' + (someDate.getMonth() + 1);
```

The `(someDate.getMonth() + 1)` is required because `getMonth()` returns the zero-indexed month. Meaning January is `0`, February is `1` and so on.

**Using Moment.js**

Look into a library like . Using Moment you can format dates in endless ways:

```
moment(someDateD).format('DD/MM');
```

Here's your [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/unzmf2kh/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function that handles it if you don't need any other complex manipulations with dates.

```
function formateDate(date) {
  function addZero_(num) {
    return num < 10 ? ('0' + num) : num);
  }
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  return addZero_(day) + '/' + addZero_(month);
}

document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = formateDate(someDateD);
```

Also use `for` to set date values in dom.